# take text from .txt file and insert into string in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

Using Python 3.7

I want to grab the info from a text_file.text to insert into a URL.

I have searched the forums for quite sometime now and just can't find the right post.

I appreciate any and all help. Thanks

here's what i have:

```
URL_FORMAT = 'http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV{}&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors'

def get_LIC_Number():
    with open (test_file.txt, 'r') as f:
        return (f.read())

url = URL_FORMAT.format(get_LIC_Number())

print(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f.read returns the whole file as a string. Because you only want one word, you can split it the input on the space character then take the first index

```
URL_FORMAT = 'ThisIs{}Frustrating.com'

def get_Very_Dirty_Word():
    with open(DirtyWord, 'r') as f:
        return f.read().split()[0]

url = URL_FORMAT.format(get_Very_Dirty_Word())

print(url)
```

Also I assume DirtyWord contains "filename.txt". Hope this helps!

Comment: I just updated the initial question and what i'm looking to do.  I also updated the info to reflect the actual code.  When i try to run what Deejpake suggested, i get NameError: name 'test_file' is not defined.  what gives?

Answer (score 0):

lol....guess i had to actually define "test_file".

URL_FORMAT = 'http://www.wvlabor.com/new_searches/contractor_RESULTS.cfm?wvnumber=WV{}&contractor_name=&dba=&city_name=&County=&Submit3=Search+Contractors'

LIC_Number = 'test_file.txt'

def Get_LIC_Number():
    with open(LIC_Number, 'r') as f:
        return f.read().split()[0]

url = URL_FORMAT.format(Get_LIC_Number())

print(url)